# Where is save data stored for Flywrench?

Tags: flywrench

I want to transfer save progress for Flywrench between computers. The game's [Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/337350/Flywrench/) mentions the game has support for Steam Cloud, but the automatic save sync isn't working for me.

Where does *Flywrench* store it's save data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Flywrench Wiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Flywrench#Configuration_files_and_save_game_data_location)

> Save locations:
>
> Windows:  %LOCALAPPDATA%/FlywrenchStudio/
>
> Linux:  ~/.config/FlywrenchStudio/